# Recognise actual type of uploaded file?

Tags: c#

I allow users to upload certain files to my server, and I'd like to validate that they've not changed the file extension. For example, a user might rename a `.bat` file to `.xlsx` and then upload it.

I'm attempting to detect the true file type. For Office documents (`.docx`, etc.), I can open the file as a ZIP file and look for a well-known directory (`word/` for `.docx`, `xl/` for `.xlsx`, etc.).

I'm using the following code:

```
private static FileType CheckForCompressFile(FileType type, string fileFullName)
{
    FileType result = null;
    using (var zipFile = ZipFile.OpenRead(fileFullName))
    {
        if (zipFile.Entries.Any(e => e.FullName.StartsWith("word/")))
            result = WORDX;
        else if (zipFile.Entries.Any(e => e.FullName.StartsWith("xl/")))
            result = EXCELX;
        else if (zipFile.Entries.Any(e => e.FullName.StartsWith("ppt/")))
             result = PPTX;
         else if (zipFile.Entries.Any(e => e.FullName.StartsWith("sbt/")))
             result = JAR;
         else
             result = CheckForOdtAndOds(result, zipFile);
    }
    return result;
  }
```

But the ZIP support in `System.IO` is only available in .NET 4.5, and I need to use .NET 4.0. What are my options?

Comment: There's two questions here. And what do you mean by *file base*?

Comment: What do you mean "extension of file base"? Are you looking to figure out that you really have an Excel file, and not a Word file?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: From what the code does, I'd say yes.

Comment: Also, are you really asking how to use `System.IO.ZipFile` in .NET 4, and you can simply leave out all the code related to a open document formatted file?

Comment: And finally I'll cheat you by creating a ZIP file with folders  `word`, `xl` AND `ppt` and then rename it to docx.

Comment: You could see if `ZipPackage` fits your needs, if not then you probably have to resort to a 3rd party library.

Comment: Ex: I have a file: test.xlsx . And then i change to extension: test.docx (or test.txt). How to detect extension file is .xlsx.

Comment: Yes,we understand that but...why are you doing that? it's a nonsense

Comment: because my app validate function upload file to server. I have a list prevent to upload file ( .xls; .exe; .bat;...) . If user change extension and then upload file to server

Comment: I've edited the question to include those details, and to replace the term "file base". I hope that my edits are OK.

Comment: But there are actually two questions here: (1) how do I validate users' uploads? and (2) how do I open `.docx`, etc., files in .NET 4.0.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe. your edit is OK. My question is : how do I validate users' uploads?

Comment: I think the file "xlsx, docx, pptx" is format zip type

Comment: See my updated answer. I think it is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is not easy, i'm sorry. In previous Office versions, you could tell apart the file type by reading the first bytes of the file and checking the signature there. But in the new `xlsx`,`docx`...formats, they all share the same signature because they are compressed files, so they all start with 'PK..'. You can check what i say this way:

```
byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"file.docx");
string signature = ((char)fileBytes[0]).ToString() + ((char)fileBytes[1]).ToString();
Console.WriteLine(signature);
```

This would write 'PK',no matter if its a word,excel,powerpoint file...

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) you have a list of different file types signatures. There you'll see that all office documents share the same.

**Edit**

Ok, now I understand what you are doing. You want to decompress the office files to tell the filetype apart. You can do it like this:

```
private static FileType CheckForCompressFile(FileType type, string fileFullName)
{
   FileType result = null;
   FileStream fileBytes = new FileStream(fileFullName, FileMode.Open);
        using (System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive zipFile = new System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive(fileBytes))
        {
            if (zipFile.Entries.Any(e => e.FullName.StartsWith("word/")))
                result = WORDX;
            else if (zipFile.Entries.Any(e => e.FullName.StartsWith("xl/")))
                result = EXCELX;
            else if (zipFile.Entries.Any(e => e.FullName.StartsWith("ppt/")))
                result = PPTX;
            else if (zipFile.Entries.Any(e => e.FullName.StartsWith("sbt/")))
                result = JAR;
            else
                result = CheckForOdtAndOds(result, zipFile);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

You must add a reference to [Compression namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to use it in Net 4.0. I also advise you to use my previous signature solution to decide if the file is a compressed file before calling this method.

**Edit 2**

If you need this for Net4.0, I advise you to use a free Zip library, as [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/). It's easy to use. Just download the zip from the link,uncompress the file `Ionic.Zip.dll` from the `zip-v1.9\Release` folder,add a reference to this file in your proyect and then just do this:

```
private static FileType CheckForCompressFile(string fileFullName)
{
    FileType result = null;

    using (Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zipFile = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile(fileFullName))
    {
        if (zipFile.Entries.Any(e => e.FileName.StartsWith("word/")))
            result = WORDX;
        else if (zipFile.Entries.Any(e => e.FileName.StartsWith("xl/")))
            result = EXCELX;
        else if (zipFile.Entries.Any(e => e.FileName.StartsWith("ppt/")))
            result = PPTX;
        else if (zipFile.Entries.Any(e => e.FileName.StartsWith("sbt/")))
            result = JAR;
        else
            result = CheckForOdtAndOds(result, zipFile);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. I try it, but not work: " cannot resolve symbol "ZipArchive".  Net 4.0 not support zipfile and ziparchive

Comment: Have you added the reference to `System.IO.Compression` in your proyect?

Comment: @ngocchaunguyen I was wrong, `System.IO.Compression` is not available in Net 4.0. See my second edit for an alternative. I have tried it and it works just fine. Hope it helps

Comment: I have download and add reference. But i can't using Ionic.Zip

Comment: You must have done something wrong with the reference,because i've tried and it works. Make sure you have extracted the right dll (Ionic.Zip.dll inside zip-v1.9\Release folder) and that you have the reference in your proyect explorer below `References`.

Comment: I have recheck. It's using, thanks for your support.

Comment: I'm sorry. I add reference wrong project. Now, i can using and it working. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the System.IO.Packaging namespace, which contains support for ZIP files, but not all of the features of ZIP files.